# How to save the screen controls?

Tags: ios, ios7

In my application i have some widgets in which user shall able to view the analytics,then they have an option to save the current screen controls for later analysis.I wondering how to save the UI controls of the screen and reopen those again.anyone help me how to accomplish this.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for [State Preservation and Restoration](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/StatePreservation/StatePreservation.html)

Follow up these below tutorials

http://useyourloaf.com/blog/2013/05/21/state-preservation-and-restoration.html